# How to insert the result of this code into a existing table in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have to insert the output of this code into an already existing table. How can I achieve this? I did it, but the output is getting appended to the previous result of the table.

Code:

```
DECLARE @KPI_BU TABLE (BU NVARCHAR(MAX)) 

INSERT @KPI_BU 
SELECT @BU 

Declare @KTV table(Business_Unit nvarchar(max), KPI nvarchar(max),YTD_Plan money, Actual money, Deviation money, Year_Plan money )

DECLARE BU_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
SELECT BU FROM @KPI_BU 

OPEN BU_cursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM BU_cursor INTO @BU 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
INSERT @KTV(Business_Unit, KPI, YTD_Plan, Actual, Deviation, Year_Plan) 
EXEC dbo.SP_KPI_History @FiscalYear, @BU 

FETCH NEXT FROM BU_cursor INTO @BU 
END 

CLOSE BU_cursor 
DEALLOCATE BU_cursor 

--SELECT * FROM @KTV
```

And if I provide

```
SELECT * 
into KPI_History
FROM @KTV
```

in place of the commented line it creates a new table and inserts the result into it. I want to insert the RESULT into already existing table.

**Update**

@Mikael;

I don't know whether i was able to make u understand my question or not. Sorry for that.

What i want is, Now i have two table with this columns:

KPI_History with(Businessunit,KPI_Name,YTD,Actual,Deviation,..)

KPI_codes with (KPI_Name, KPI_code)

In **KPI_history** table i want to use the **KPI_Code** of **KPI_Codes table** instead of **KPI_name** of **KPI_History table**. As KPI_Names are too long strings and i have created short codes for the KPI_Names and valued them into KPI_Code. i.e. KPI_code table consist of the KPI names and the codes for the KPI_Names.

So output should be:
KPI_Table with (Businessunit,KPI_Name[It sholud contain codes from KPI_History table],YTD,etc.)

Hope i was able to make you guys understand what i am asking for. :|

Comment: post the output of this procedure...

Comment: It shows me the table as output, but I want to insert the same into existing table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to insert the RESULT into already existing table.

Here is how you insert into an existing table:

```
insert into KPI_History (Business_Unit, KPI, YTD_Plan, Actual, Deviation, Year_Plan)
select Business_Unit, KPI, YTD_Plan, Actual, Deviation, Year_Plan
from @KTV;
```

> but the output is getting appended to the previous result of the
>   table.

So you don't want the result to be added to `KPI_History`? Then I guess you just have to delete the rows in `KPI_History` before inserting.

```
delete from KPI_History;

insert into KPI_History (Business_Unit, KPI, YTD_Plan, Actual, Deviation, Year_Plan)
select Business_Unit, KPI, YTD_Plan, Actual, Deviation, Year_Plan
from @KTV;
```

**Update:**

If you need information from another table in the insert you can just join to that table.
Something like this might work for you.

```
insert into KPI_History
  (Business_Unit,
   KPI,
   YTD_Plan,
   Actual,
   Deviation,
   Year_Plan, 
   Code)
select K.Business_Unit,
       K.KPI, 
       K.YTD_Plan,
       K.Actual,
       K.Deviation,
       K.Year_Plan,
       C.Code
from @KTV as K
  inner join KPI_Code as C
    on K.KPI = C.KPI;
```

Comment: Sorry to mention this above but the table in which i have to update the data contains one Extra column named "TS". So will this piece of code solve my issue?

Comment: And one more thing, After getting the result into KPI_History table i want to join History table to Code table.

Comment: @Pankaj - If the columns don't match you have to specify the column names like I have done and not use `select *`. So I guess it should work just fine but you will of course not have any values in `TS` unless you specify a constant expression in the select or have a default value defined on the column.

Comment: @Pankaj "i want to join History table to Code table" I have no idea what that means. Please update your question. BTW, I guess the code you have provided is not your actual code. As is, there is no need at all to have a cursor in there.

Comment: Sorry, It wasn't getting posted..

Question is:

And one more thing, After getting the result into KPI_History table i want to join KPI_History table to KPI_Code table.

History table contains above mentioned columns. Code table contains two columns "KPI", and "Code". I want KPI_History table to contain code column of KPI_Code table instead of KPI of KPI_History table.

Help.

Comment: Yeah this is the actual code but with modification, cursor i have used to loop over a particular BU from all 10 BU's. 

After posting here i updated my code and now i am able to get the data into history table.

Please help for joining the table.

Comment: I tried your updated code, but the problem is instead of showing30 rows it is showing me 90 rows as a result.

Comment: @Pankaj - Since I don't see your data I really can't help you with that. I think you should change the description of your question (or ask a new one) to include table structures for all involved tables, describe the relations between the tables, some sample data in the tables and your expected output. Your original question was "How to insert into an existing table". Now it is something else.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience. I am Posting the same in other post.